# Getting HTML input value and using that value as a Java variable

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, api

Sorry for the long post and janky question.

I'm trying to figure out how to use an input textbox inside a form as a way to get the name of a city. With the city name, I'll then use it inside a method (getCitybyId) inside the MainController.

I'll then use it as the city name inside my api URL
Example:"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=**citynamevariable**&appid=APIKey&units=imperial"

Is there any way I could do this? I'm pretty new to using spring boot and API's, and I have been trying to figure this out for a while.

Here's my code

MainController:

```
@RestController
public class MainController extends HttpServlet {

    DataRepo dataRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get(@RequestParam("name") String id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView ("redirect:/");
        String city = getCitybyId(id);
        try{
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(city);
            mv.addObject("Name", json.getString("name"));
            mv.addObject("Temperature", json.getJSONObject("main").get("temp").toString());
            mv.addObject("feels_like", json.getJSONObject("main").get("feels_like").toString());
            mv.addObject("humidity", json.getJSONObject("main").get("humidity").toString());
            mv.addObject("Wind", json.getJSONObject("wind").get("speed").toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return mv;
    }


    private String getCitybyId(String name) {

        try {
            String apiKey = "key";
            URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=PUTCITYNAMEHERE&appid=key&units=imperial");

            // These two are test to see if the method is actually getting data.
            //String apiKey = "key";
            // URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("https://superheroapi.com/api/" + apiKey + "/" + id);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

            int status = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(status);
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                return response.toString();
            }

            else {
                return "Unexpected HTTP response";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class City
{
    private String name;
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public City()
    {
        name = "DEFAULT";
    }
    public City(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

```
HTML code

    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title> Homework 4 application</title>
    <style><%@include file ="../css/style.css"%></style>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Please Select A City</h1>
    <form method="get" action="/get/">
        <input type="text" id = "name" name="name"  />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <div>
        <h2>City</h2> <h3><%=request.getParameter("Name")%></h3>
        <h2>Temperature</h2> <h3><%=request.getParameter("Temperature")%> Fahrenheit</h3>
        <h2>Feels Like</h2> <h3><%=request.getParameter("feels_like")%> Fahrenheit</h3>
        <h2>Humidity</h2> <h3><%=request.getParameter("humidity")%>%</h3>
        <h2>Wind Speed</h2> <h3><%=request.getParameter("Wind")%> Mph</h3>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div>
        <h2>Previously Requested Cities</h2>

        <table class = "lemun">
            <tr>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Temperature</td>
                <td>Feels Like</td>
                <td>Humidity</td>
                <td>Wind Speed</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var = "Data" items = "${dataList}">
            <tr>
                <td>${Data.getName}</td>
                <td>${Data.getTemperature}</td>
                <td>${Data.getFeels_Like}</td>
                <td>${Data.getHumidity}</td>
                <td>${Data.getWind}</td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
    </hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Basically, I'm trying to use the User input from the textbox as a value for the cityname inside the openweathermap URL. Is this possible? If so may you show a way to do it?

Comment: What actual problem are you having? Have you tried just putting the city name in your URL where you have `PUTCITYNAMEHERE`?

Comment: The problem I'm having is trying to get the input from the textbox inside the form. Then using the value typed in as the city name inside the URL. So user inputs cityname inside textbox --> cityname is then passed onto the java controller --> cityname is used inside the URL. Sorry if I worded the question weirdly. Also I have but i'm trying to get user input as the cityname.

Comment: And which part of that sequence is giving you trouble?

Comment: Mostly the html to java part. I just can't figure out how to get the value from the textbox and transfer it over to the java controller.